# How to setup latest Dozer version?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, hibernate-mapping, dozer

I need to use [Dozer 6.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dozermapper/dozer-core/6.5.0) (because of [this](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/172)) so I added the following snippet from MVNrepository into my `pom.xml`.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dozermapper/dozer-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The project builds, but there are multiple problems.

1. Old version of Dozer is used instead. I know that, because my logs refer to `~[dozer-5.5.1.jar:na]` and the bug persists.
2. IntelliJ complains that `Dependency 'com.github.dozermapper:dozer-core:6.5.0' not found`.

I think it uses the older version from some other maven repository I use. It imports `org.dozer.Mapper`. How can I use the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems.

- It was a Maven multi-module project and the subproject was using the old Dozer version setup in its `pom.xml`
- The Dozer library was not downloaded by Maven for some reason. I had to download it and set it up manually. I deleted the jar files of old Maven in File >> Project Structure >> Libraries and imported the new Dozer library I downloaded [elsewhere](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dozermapper/dozer-core/6.5.0).

Now it works. Don't know why the Dozer JAR was not retrieved automatically by Maven, though.